# R: Which variables to include in model?

Tags: r, statistics

I'm fairly new to R and am currently trying to find the best model to predict my dependent variable from a number of predictor variables. I have 20 precictor variables and I want to see which ones I should include in my model and which ones I should exclude.

I am currently just running models with different predictor variables in each and comparing them to see which one has the lowest AIC, but this is taking a really long time. Is there an easier way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, use penalized regression, such as LASSO.

Comment: hi,

i'm voting to close this question as it doesn't concern R programming. perhaps try http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a theoretical question actually...

In principle, if all of the predictors are actually exogenous to the model, they can all be included together and assuming you have enough data (N >> 20) and they are not too similar (which could give rise to multi-collinearity), that should help prediction. In practice, you need to think about whether each of (or any of) your predictors are actually exogenous to the model (that is, independent of the error term in the model). If they are not, then they will impart a bias on the estimates. (Also, omitting explanatory variables that are actually necessary imparts a bias.)

If predictive accuracy (even spurious in-sample accuracy) is the goal, then techniques like LASSO (as mentioned in the comments) could also help.